# Debunking Stroustrup's debunking of the myth “C++ is for large, complicated, programs only”

Tags: popularity-contest, parsing, regular-expression, internet

[Stroustrup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bjarne_Stroustrup) has recently posted a series of posts debunking [popular myths about C++](http://isocpp.org/blog/2014/12/myths-3). The fifth myth is: “C++ is for large, complicated, programs only”. To debunk it, he wrote a simple C++ program **downloading a web page and extracting links from it**. Here it is:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <regex>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using namespace std;

set<string> get_strings(istream& is, regex pat)
{
    set<string> res;
    smatch m;
    for (string s; getline(is, s);)  // read a line
        if (regex_search(s, m, pat))
            res.insert(m[0]);              // save match in set
    return res;
}

void connect_to_file(iostream& s, const string& server, const string& file)
// open a connection to server and open an attach file to s
// skip headers
{
    if (!s)
        throw runtime_error{ "can't connect\n" };

    // Request to read the file from the server:
    s << "GET " << "http://" + server + "/" + file << " HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    s << "Host: " << server << "\r\n";
    s << "Accept: */*\r\n";
    s << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

    // Check that the response is OK:
    string http_version;
    unsigned int status_code;
    s >> http_version >> status_code;

    string status_message;
    getline(s, status_message);
    if (!s || http_version.substr(0, 5) != "HTTP/")
        throw runtime_error{ "Invalid response\n" };

    if (status_code != 200)
        throw runtime_error{ "Response returned with status code" };

    // Discard the response headers, which are terminated by a blank line:
    string header;
    while (getline(s, header) && header != "\r")
        ;
}

int main()
{
    try {
        string server = "www.stroustrup.com";
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream s{ server, "http" };  // make a connection
        connect_to_file(s, server, "C++.html");    // check and open file

        regex pat{ R"((http://)?www([./#\+-]\w*)+)" }; // URL
        for (auto x : get_strings(s, pat))    // look for URLs
            cout << x << '\n';
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Let's show Stroustrup what **small and readable** program actually is.

1. Download `http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html`
2. List all links:

   ```
    http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/languages/C++.html
    http://www.accu.org
    http://www.artima.co/cppsource
    http://www.boost.org
    ...
   ```

You can use any language, but no third-party libraries are allowed.

## Winner

[C++ answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44344) won by votes, but it relies on a semi-third-party library (which is disallowed by rules), and, along with another close competitor [Bash](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44317), relies on a hacked together HTTP client (it won't work with HTTPS, gzip, redirects etc.). So [**Wolfram**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44316) is a clear winner. Another solution which comes close in terms of size and readability is [PowerShell](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44331) (with improvement from comments), but it hasn't received much attention. Mainstream languages ([Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44279), [C#](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44283)) came pretty close too.

## Comment on subjectivity

The most upvoted answer (C++) at the moment votes were counted was **disqualified for not following the rules** listed here in the question. There's nothing subjective about it. The second most upvoted question at that moment (Wolfram) was declared winner. The third answer's (Bash) "disqualification" is subjective, but it's **irrelevant** as the answer didn't win by votes at any point in time. You can consider it a comment if you like. Furthermore, right now the Wolfram answer is the most upvoted answer, the accepted one, and is declared winner, which means there's zero debate or subjectivity.

Comment: Comments purged as they were all either obsolete or off-topic.

Comment: Clarification: Shall the list of links be as incomplete as Stroustrup's one, i.e. skip any non-http-links that don't include `www` (including the https, ftp, local and anchor ones on that very site) and report false-positives, i.e. non-linked mentions of `http://` as well (not here, but in general)?

Comment: Why is pointing out that ALL of the posted answers don't apply to what the OP asked, obsolete or off-topic?

Comment: To each his own, I've been called worse. If the OP's goal wasn't to try and somehow prove that Stroustrup is wrong, then I'd agree with your assessment. But the entire premise of the question is to show how "your favorite language" can do the same thing as this 50 lines of C++ in much less lines of code. The problem is that none of the examples do the same thing. In particular, none of the answers perform any error checking, none of the answers provide reusable functions, most of the answers don't provide a complete program. The Stroustrup example provides all of that.

Comment: [What's sad is his web page isn't even valid UTF-8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27844778/what-can-cause-rusts-tcpsocketwrite-to-return-invalid-input). Now I've gotta work around that, despite his server advertising `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`... I'm gonna email him.

Comment: I wish I'd thought of coming here and asking this question when I read that piece. Certainly C++ is better than it was in the past, but it's by no means optimal.

Comment: @Dunk The other examples don't provide reusable functions because they accomplish the entire functionality of those functions in a single line and it makes no sense to make that a whole function on its own, and the C++ example doesn't perform any error checking that isn't handled natively in almost an identical manner, and the phrase "complete program" is almost meaningless.

Comment: "You can use any language, but no third-party libraries are allowed." I don't think that's a fair requirement considering `boost/asio` is used up there which *is* a third-party library. I mean how will languages that don't include url/tcp fetching as part of its standard library compete?

Comment: @greatwolf They don't. That's the point.

Comment: @Jason - upvote for "C++ example doesn't perform any error checking that isn't handled natively in almost an identical manner".

Comment: Virtually all the answers fail the task (including the original lol) because they don't pick up relative links! I did mine herE: http://forum.dlang.org/thread/tqegmjcofcnwapqitrdo@forum.dlang.org#post-nxcpwmyjfbfbjxqtmrzd:40forum.dlang.org

Comment: Is nobody gonna talk about using regexes to parse HTML? Really? I mean Stroustrup does it himself but at least his regex doesn't rely on the HTML-attribute using `"` and only ever `"` to delimit its value. 9 out of 10 answers here would fail on `<a href='http://htmlparsing.com/regexes.html'>`

Comment: @funkwurm Problems with the provided solutions have been mentioned many times, you just need to look through comments. The famous "parsing HTML with regex" answer from SO has been brought up too. Many comments have been removed by the mod though.

Comment: @undergroundmonorail BF++ does. It is giving me strange and deviant thoughts.

Comment: I have to admit, I'm surprised by Stroustrup's claim that most people believe that C++ is used for large programs. I (probably incorrectly) believe the opposite - that for large programs, it's worthwhile to use a language like Java or C# that makes it harder to shoot yourself in the foot!

Comment: Its a little odd to me that Stroustrup's challenge is to write C++ code that imports no third party code and the first line (or so, I'm not going to page back and lose my post thus far) is an import of boost's asio library. It kind of makes OP's opinion suspect. But in any case, comparing different languages in this task is very much like comparing apples and oranges. It doesn't really make much sense to use a hammer to tap in a pin, but it can be done; it doesn't make much sense to write assembly code to extract url's from a web page but it can be done. I suspect you could write a RoR program

Comment: He's... [parsing... html... with... regex...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1678468) *twitch*

Comment: This code snippet appears in a hacking scene on the Netflix series "Limitless"; Season 1, Episode 10, ~13:05. Proof: http://i.imgur.com/7a16H8y.png

Comment: I'm casting a close vote as lacking an objective winning criterion because the question is tagged [tag:popularity-contest], but the "winner" paragraph at the end suggests the OP is subjectively disqualifying answers.

Comment: @pppery I really wonder what are you trying to achieve by closing this question.

Comment: @pppery The most upvoted answer (C++) at the moment votes were counted was **disqualified for not following the rules** listed in question. There's nothing subjective about it. The second most upvoted question at that moment (Wolfram) was declared winner. The third answer's (Bash) "disqualification" is subjective, but it's **irrelevant** as the answer didn't win by votes at any point in time. You can consider it a comment if you like. Furthermore, right now the Wolfram answer is the most upvoted answer, the accepted one, and is declared winner, which means there's zero debate or subjectivity.

Comment: @pppery Does that mean that if the OP edited out the “Winner” section and just left the answer accepted without any comments the question would have an objective winning criteria? I agree with the OP here, pop-con is objective, and “no third party libraries”, while not a great thing to ban, still disqualifies the C++ answer, making the Wolfram answer the clear winner. Flag the C++ answer in invalid and deletion, don’t close the question because of one bad (debatable but not my point) answer

Comment: OK, you've convinced me. I'll vote to re-open as soon as the C++ answer is [deleted by a moderator](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7990/46076) (which should have been done in the first place rather than disqualifying it from the winning criteria)

Comment: And my flag was resolved without the answer being deleted, so this question is now in a chicken-egg situation leaving no resolution other than remaining closed.

Comment: @pppery What rule do you follow exactly that says to close a question if one answer violates its rules? Besides closing a question for zero practical reasons other than virtual points, all you have achieved is wasting of time. You can't reopen the question anyway, you aren't a mod.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

## Wolfram

This feels like complete cheating

```js
Import["http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html", "Hyperlinks"]
```

So just add some honest parsing on top

```js
Cases[
 Import["http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html", "XMLObject"],
 XMLElement["a", {___, "href" -> link_, ___}, ___] :> 
  link /; StringMatchQ[link, RegularExpression["((http://)?www([./#\\+-]\\w*)+)"]]
, Infinity]
```

Comment: Nope, I don't see any cheating here. This challenge is about bringing out the best of your language. And that first line is the epitome of "small and readable".

Comment: An answer that can ignore the silly arguments about catching ftp links.  Brilliant.

Comment: Came here to offer this exact solution, pleased to see others have appreciated it as well.

Comment: @MartinBüttner In that case you might want to consider downvoting http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1078/12130

Comment: @DavidMulder Who says I didn't? ;)

Comment: @MartinBüttner Ah, if you're aware of it then you should probably enforce the community consensus though~ (and try to change the consensus if you feel so inclined).

Comment: @DavidMulder Technically, the loophole is currently not valid, since the vote breakdown is +41/-21 (and the loophole question states that loopholes are accepted if there are at least twice as many upvotes as downvotes). A close call, admittedly, but still. ;) Furthermore, this is a popularity contest, not a code golf, and in particular, it's a pop-con about showing how easily this can be done in a given language, which is why I think the loophole doesn't really apply to this challenge anyway (since the challenge basically asks for it).

Comment: @MartinBüttner Oh nice~, I couldn't check that. Sooo, is anything stopping people right now from adding a purpose build function to their codegolf language forks for each new question? That seems the 'sensible' next step in that case~ (It's the problem I have with most of these challenges, languages like OpenEdge, ColdFusion and Wolfram are what I tend to call framework languages, because they contain not just a language itself, but also very high level purpose build languages you would normally find in frameworks and/or libraries. The true strength of a language is not in the number of

Comment: purpose build functions, but in the easy of access to such a function if you need it. For example with node.js this would be a `npm install jsdom` call, whereas with Mathematica you have to search the interwebs for the libraries you need).

Comment: @DavidMulder That's a different issue. Only languages (and language versions) which were available before a challenge was posted, may be used in that challenge. If you want to discuss this further, [feel free to join us in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte).

Comment: @MartinBüttner: Actually, it's bashing C++ for not declaring "everything and the kitchen sink" to be part of the standard library, and thus making it unsuitable for really small devices, restricted environments, and other situations...

Comment: I suppose, this `Import` statement does true Html parsing rather than the original code’s naive regex matching. So it’s not equivalent. It’s closer to what you likely want in real life, but still, not doing the same as the original…

Answer (score 114):

## C++

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::string server = "www.stroustrup.com";
    std::string request = "GET http://" + server + "/C++.html HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: " + server + "\r\n\r\n";
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream s{server, "http"};
    s << request;
    std::regex pat{R"((http://)?www([./#\+-]\w*)+)"};
    std::smatch m;
    for (std::string l; getline(s, l);)
        if (std::regex_search(l, m, pat))
            std::cout << m[0] << "\n";
}
```

The main shortcoming is the awkward nature of boost::asio, I'm sure it can be even shorter with a better library.

Comment: I think using boost is fair, since large parts of it have been integrated into the standard library in the past, and there have been plans to integrate asio in a future version.

Comment: What about `ftp://ftp.research.att.com/pub/c++std/WP/CD2` and `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jDqQudbtuqo&feature=youtu.be`?

Comment: `using std::string;` would somewhat simplify the code (and will make the long line short enough so as not to require the horizontal scrolling bar).

Comment: @DevSolar You can consider boost a part of the standard library for C++ if you wish, it's a staging area for the standard library anyway. However, even with boost, you still have to know inner workings of HTTP protocol. It may look simple in this sample, but imagine you need to support HTTPS, gzip, redirects etc. Will it be as simple? Bare TCP socket quickly becomes insufficient.

Comment: you don't need `Host` header in `HTTP/1.0`

Comment: "even shorter with a better library" well naturally if the library offers a `importHyperLinks(std::string url)` function.

Answer (score 88):

## Pure Bash on Linux/OS X (no external utilities)

HTTP client software is notoriously bloated.  We don't want those kinds of dependencies.  Instead we can push the appropriate headers down a TCP stream and read the result.  No need to call archaic utilities like grep or sed to parse the result.

```bash
domain="www.stroustrup.com"
path="C++.html"
exec 3<> /dev/tcp/$domain/80
printf "GET /$path HTTP/1.1\r\nhost: %s\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n" "$domain" >&3
while read -u3; do
    if [[ "$REPLY" =~ http://[^\"]* ]]; then
        printf '%s\n' "$BASH_REMATCH"
    fi
done
```

Meh - I suppose it could be more readable...

Comment: Like this one using unix file handles for the pipes.

Comment: Wow, never thought one can do this without external utils. Although it seems my bash 3.2.17 on LFS is a tiny bit obsolete so that doesn't support `mapfile` :)

Comment: @Ruslan Yep, `mapfile` comes with bash 4.x.  The same thing is totally doable with a `while read` loop as well.

Comment: @Ruslan I changed it to `while read` instead of `mapfile`.  More portable and more readable, I think.

Comment: Works on OS X, too!

Comment: Very nice.  I think it fails when you have two links on the same line though.  Also sadly the original link now redirects to https.

Answer (score 66):

## Python 2

```py
import urllib2 as u, re
s = "http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html"
w = u.urlopen(s)
h = w.read()
l = re.findall('"((http)s?://.*?)"', h)
print l
```

Lame, but works

Comment: Why not chain a lot of those calls? `l = re.findall('"((http)s?://.*?)"', u.urlopen(s).read())`

Comment: It is short but it is not idiomatic (readability counts in Python)

Comment: Hmmm...if all my code ignored errors like this example then 75% to 90% of my work would already be done on every project I work on.

Comment: What about `ftp://ftp.research.att.com/pub/c++std/WP/CD2`? And the output is not a plain list but a list of tuples...

Comment: @TobiasKienzler the reference C++ code doesn't catch the ftp urls either.

Comment: @jwg Indeed. I [asked for clarification](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44278/debunking-stroustrups-debunking-of-the-myth-c-is-for-large-complicated-pro#comment103767_44278) on that. Generalizing the regex shouldn't be too difficult, nonetheless I prefer avoiding regex in this case.[.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44358/2775).

Comment: @Dunk: Suppose the example did catch some exception (e.g. from `urlopen()`).  What should it do with such an exception, other than crash and die?  If it's going to crash and die anyway, why not just let Python handle the crashing-and-dying, and leave off the exception handling altogether?

Comment: @Kevin:My nit is that this answer (and none of the others) answer the OP's challenge as asked. The Stroustrup code example does more than the answers. This gives the misleading appearance that the answers can do the same thing in less lines of code. The fact is that none of the answers are doing the same as the original code. So it isn't an apples to apples comparison. As for why not let Python handle the crashing and dying, because someone might actually want to use the code in an actual program. Stroustrup's example code allows one to do so.

Comment: @Dunk: If I were using somebody else's Python code, I'd much rather they *not* catch `urlopen` errors than (say) catch them and call `sys.exit("something's borked!")`.  If they do the latter, I have to catch `SystemExit`, which is never fun.

Comment: you don't need `(http)` to be in a group.`(https?://.*?)` works just as well

Comment: Use raw strings in RegEx.

Answer (score 53):

## C#

```cs
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string html = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html");
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(html, @"https?://[^""]+"))
    Console.WriteLine(match);
```

Comment: You can use `var html`, and probably `var match` to shave off a few characters.

Comment: @Superbest I can make names single-character and get rid of `html` variable altogether too, but it's not what I'm after.

Comment: @Superbest not [tag:code-golf]. :D

Comment: Well, it improves readability, too. Is there ever a reason not to use `var` when it won't impact code semantics?

Comment: @Superbest: "it improves readability" is subjective. Personally, I think explicitly stating the type of the variable improves readability (usually, like in this code here). I don't want to debate this, though; I just want to point out that alternative views exist.

Comment: If you don't know what object type is returned by a method "var" makes reading other peoples code (exploring libraries unknown to you) more difficult and time consuming. Say you read "var name = GetName()". Is it a string? Or something else? You can't know without checking.

Comment: But `var` actually says "don't care", so the `GetName()` may change the return type to an unrelated one, as long as it still gives me what I am looking for.

Comment: @Superbest you can't use `var` for `Match` anyway, since `MatchCollection` only implments `ICollection`. This is a major PITA if you ask me, and `GetEnumerator` [can't be changed](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/271) without breaking changes.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski `var` can be used in this sample, you'll get `object`, which is sufficient for `Console.WriteLine`.

Comment: @Athari oh right, I didn't read carefully enough

Comment: If you care about the use of `var` go here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c-sharp

Comment: Personally I think this code is more readable than some of the other answers, even if it's not as short.

Comment: With the latest C#, you can omit class and function Main.

Comment: @Vlad Improved my answer, thanks. However, with high-ranked users closing the question for purely subjective reasons (I mean, nobody likes admitting that every question is technically a [tag:popularity-contest], but come on), I don't think there's much point in improving answers to the question which will receive very few views.

Answer (score 52):

## "No third-party" is a fallacy

I think the "no third-party" assumption is a fallacy. And is a specific fallacy that afflicts C++ developers, since it's so hard to make reusable code in C++.  When you are developing anything at all, even if it's a small script, you will always make use of whatever pieces of reusable code are available to you.

The thing is, in languages like Perl, Python, Ruby (to name a few), reusing someone else's code is not only easy, but it is how most people actually write code most of the time.

C++, with its nearly impossible-to-maintain-compatible-ABI-requirements makes that a much tougher job, you end up with a project like Boost, which is a monstrous repository of code and very little composability outside it.

### A CPAN example

Just for the fun of it, here goes a CPAN-based example, with proper parsing of the html, instead of [trying to use regex to parse html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use HTML::LinkExtor;
sub callback {
   my ($tag, %links) = @_;
   print map { "$_\n" } values %links
}
$p = HTML::LinkExtor->new(\&callback, "http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html");
```

Comment: That HTML answer, funny as it is, is a fallacy. "HTML is not a regular language and hence cannot be parsed by regular expressions." is true, but HTML _tags_ definitely _are_ a regular language, and something to turn a stream into bite-sized chunks of tags and text nodes would serve a similar purpose to a lexer. Reminds me of that supposed monster regex purportedly necessary for parsing email addresses, when what it's actually parsing is a different RFC822 element than the one we generally consider to be an email address.

Comment: From the point of view of a Perl hacker, the entire CPAN is part of Perl's standard library :)

Comment: Upvote for addressing the point of the 3rd party libs, but: crap, *making* reusable *code* in C++ is as easy cheesy as in other language. *Using* and especially **finding** reusable **code** may be a tad harder, but the only thing that's seriously problematic is reusing *compiled* artifacts, but that's often a non-issue in interpreted languages like Perl, etc.

Comment: To stretch an analogy, Boost is more like CPAN - pick and choose. You don't call CPAN a "monstrous repository of code" just because there's such a lot of stuff in there you don't use?

Comment: CPAN *is* a 'monstrous repository of code', by any reasonable definition of those four words.

Comment: That's not necessarily a bad thing.  :)  As long as you can pick and choose, at least.

Comment: @MartinBa I disagree, C++ being a compiled language, requiring every executable to rebuild its full stack of dependencies because it's hard to maintain ABI compatibility seriously hinders code reusability. In order to produce a reusable library in C++ you have to go through really long lengths in order to make sure you don't force yourself into ABI-incompatible changes all the time.

Comment: @jwg the difference is that CPAN is extremely composable, not only you're allowed to pick and choose which libraries to use, but they're usually made compatible against different versions of their dependencies (and the cpantesters help ensure that is true).

With Boost you may select to use just a portion of it, but you have to use it all from the same version.

Comment: You're missing a backslash on your callback.

Comment: But if you allow third-party libraries in this contest then every answer becomes `thirdPartyLibraryIJustMade.getStroustrupLinksAndPrintThem()`

Comment: @DanielRuoso - why does "producing a reusable library" entail any compilation for you? If the library just provides source code files, it is still a reusable library, isn't it?

Comment: @MartinBa because having to rebuild the whole universe everytime you want to implement a simple task is unbearable.

Comment: You have to do *something* to rule out third-party code, because otherwise every program in every language comes out as a one-liner (plus include and main boilerplate and whatnot), because you *write* a third-party module that does exactly what's asked for, publish it, and use it in "your program". The tricky question is how to draw the line in order to get a reasonable comparison between programming languages, and that in turn depends on the purpose of the comparison. Stroustrup opted not to use a proper HTTP client, which would be a most peculiar decision in real code.

Comment: @SteveJessop I disagree. I have implemented and published CPAN modules for particular tasks before and those became usable by someone else. When I started this example, I searched for HTML::Parser, I didn't even know the module for extracting the links existed, but apparently extracting the links is a common-enough problem that someone went through the trouble of posting a reusable module that does just that.

This is a fundamental aspect of the programming language, and a part where other languages (Perl in particular, but also Python and Ruby) are really good at, and C++ is really poor at.

Comment: @DanielRuoso: I mean that if Stroustrup put that code on github with a different name for the `main()` function, would you then accept that it's possible to download a webpage and extract the links in C++ in one line, that one line being `int main() { return stroustrups_thingy(); }`? Much more concise than your Perl code. Now, my C++ one-liner rather shamelessly uses a third-party library intended for the purpose of rigging this benchmark, but you think that *no* restrictions on doing that are needed in order to make meaningful comparisons between languages, right? ;-)

Comment: ... so in the end all languages are equally concise at doing anything, because all the details required to do anything can be hidden away in a benchmark-rigger library. It's like forking CJam for a particular code golf challenge so that it solves that challenge in one character. You don't *have* to ban it, but if you don't ban it you know what will happen.

Comment: Still, I like your solution since it points out that presumably without intending to, Stroustrup chose an example challenge that a Perl programmer *wouldn't even have to address*, using that CPAN module instead, since precisely the same problem has been solved before and the solution published. But if a Perl programmer did choose to address it, OK, we can look at the source of the module if we want to see how wordy it is.

Comment: @SteveJessop the problem is that in C++ the amount of reusable code is just not as large: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822581/what-c-library-should-i-use-to-implement-a-http-client  http://www.mostthingsweb.com/2013/02/parsing-html-with-c/

Comment: Mojolicious would also allow something like `use Mojo::UserAgent; say for Mojo::UserAgent->new->get("http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html")->res->dom->find("a[href^=http]")->map(attr => "href")->each`

Comment: (linebreaks could easily be added, outside of the context of an SO comment box)

Answer (score 46):

## UNIX shell

```sh
lynx -dump http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html | grep -o '\w*://.*'
```

Also finds an `ftp://` link :)

Another way, without relying on `://` syntax:

```sh
lynx -dump -listonly http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html | sed -n 's/^[ 0-9.]\+//p'
```

Comment: I can't work out whether to +1 because using a web browser to download a web page is the right tool for the job or to -1 because the challenge is to write a program to do blahblahblah and you just called a program to do the blahing.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Arguably, a web browser is the right tool to _view_ a webpage. The right tool to download a webpage is an http request. Either way, this solution is fun!

Comment: I think it's better to replace lynx with curl or wget. They are more commonly used to download a webpage.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov I chose lynx exactly because it can dump the links without me doing anything special :)

Comment: @Ruslan: that's OK, Stroustrup's code doesn't do anything special with the html either. He just regexes it for urls, which doesn't require lynx :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop by "special" I mean actually parsing or regexing or whatever. With lynx I just grep out the list of links (which curl and wget don't list) and remove the numbering. You may consider it cheating or whatever, but I thought it's fun to {use the tool which _almost perfectly_ does what is required}, just fine-tuning the output.

Comment: @Ruslan: possibly my snark at Stroustrup's code wasn't strong enough! He doesn't extract links (like lynx does), he extracts URLs. Compared with his, your code "misses" any URLs in the text that aren't links. Which normally would be a feature in your code and a bug in his, but he set the problem so maybe not :-) Not that there are any such urls on that page at the moment.

Comment: Yeah, I know, is not [tag:code-golf], but both `grep` and `sed` is an overkill. `lynx -dump http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html | grep -o '\w*://.*'`

Comment: @manatwork thanks, this is much nicer. I indeed wanted to use one filter, but didn't know of `-o` option. Edited to include this improvement.

Comment: *"but no third-party libraries are allowed"*.  I contend that `lynx` is functionally equivalent to a third-party library in this scenario.

Answer (score 44):

## CSS 3

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
*:not(a) {
  font: 0/0 monospace;
  color: transparent;
  background: transparent !important;
}
a {
  content: "";
}
a[href*="://"]::after {
  content: attr(href);
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  display: block;
  font: 12px monospace;
  color: black;
}
```

This code can be used as a user style to display only absolute links on a page in an unformatted list. It may not work correctly if your browser enforces minimum font size.

It works correctly with `http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html` (note `!important` on `background`). In order to work on other pages with more styles, it must be extended (reset more properties, mark properties as important etc.).

Alternative version which includes relative links except intrapage links starting with hashes (it relies on a hard-coded absolute link, unfortunately):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
*:not(a) {
  font: 0/0 monospace;
  color: transparent;
  background: transparent !important;
  float: none !important;
  width: auto !important;
  border: none !important;
}
a {
  content: "";
}
a::after {
  display: none;
}
a:not([href^="#"])::after {
  content: attr(href);
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  display: block;
  font: 12px monospace;
  color: black;
}
a:not([href*="://"])::after {
  content: "http://www.stroustrup.com/" attr(href);
}
```

Comment: This is the worst thing I've ever seen. +1

Comment: This is beautiful and completely horrifying. +1

Answer (score 37):

## Clojure

```lisp
(->> (slurp "http://www.stroustrup.com")
     (re-seq #"(?:http://)?www(?:[./#\+-]\w*)+"))
```

Comment: Slurp?! I need to learn Clojure.

Comment: @11684 - Clojure also has standard functions named `spit`, `zipper`, and `lazy-cat`... :-)

Comment: Wow, I think that's gonna be a late New Year's Resolution. @BobJarvis

Answer (score 33):

### Emacs Lisp

```lisp
(with-current-buffer (url-retrieve-synchronously "http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html")
  (while (re-search-forward "https?://[^\\\"]*")
    (print (match-string 0))))
```

Comment: I'm a little dissapointed, given how compact and eminently readable this code is, that it does not have more votes.  Well done.

Answer (score 28):

**Scala**

```scala
"""\"(https?://.*?)\"""".r.findAllIn(scala.io.Source.fromURL("http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html").mkString).foreach(println)
```

Comment: pack everything in one line - C++ can do it too

Comment: What about `ftp://ftp.research.att.com/pub/c++std/WP/CD2`?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl - This is one _expression_, not just one line. You can just delete all of the line breaks from the C++ code, but that's not the same thing as doing the whole task in a single expression.

Comment: @DaoWen: Sorry, but starting expressions-vs-line is just going silly. Add some functors and C++ you can do it too. But that's just the question of what libs are considered to be "granted" and have "zero code inside". It doesn't change the fact that packing it into a line hurst readability. One can keep it still as a single expression and just reformat it into a few lines to gain much and loose nothing other than .. line count. That's my point. Silly packing - C++ can do it too. If someone wants to get out of the "silly packing" box, then should format the code for readability, not linecount.

Comment: But, here's my sin there, I should have written my point clearly right away, and not try to just drop a punchline. Every day everyone learns a thing, thanks for making me think about that, DaoWen!

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: link seems broken, could you recheck?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Tobias didn't put the link there for us to follow it. He was asking the writer of this answer why it wasn't in his results.

Comment: You can't pack everything on one line in C++, if you have any #include, etc, you can't.

Comment: I tried compiling a one-liner C++ program..
prog.cpp:1:21: warning: extra tokens at end of #include directive
 #include <iostream> using namespace std; int main() { return 0; }
                     ^
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 25):

## PHP 5

```php
<?php
preg_match_all('/"(https?:\/\/.*?)"/',file_get_contents('http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html'),$m);
print_r($m[1]);
```

Comment: Suggested edits: `'/"((http)s?://.*?)"/'` ⇒ `'|"((http)s?://.*?)"|'` (currently an error); remove `array_unshift($m);` (currently an error, you likely meant `array_shift` instead); `print_r($m);` ⇒ `print_r($m[1]);` (only output the urls).

Comment: fixed, thanks for your input

Comment: @DavidXu Except you didn't fix it...?

Comment: now its fixed.!

Answer (score 23):

### PowerShell

Text search for all fully-qualified [URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) (including JavaScript, CSS, etc.):

```powershell
[string[]][regex]::Matches((iwr "http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html"), '\w+://[^"]+')
```

Or to get links in anchor tags only (includes relative URLs):

```powershell
(iwr "http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html").Links | %{ $_.href }
```

Shorter versions from comments:

```powershell
(iwr "http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html").Links.href
```

```powershell
(iwr "http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html").Links.href-match":"
```

Comment: If anyone wonders, `iwr` is an alias for `Invoke-WebRequest` (PS3+).

Comment: You could abuse PowerShell's eagerness to flatten collections and do: `(iwr "http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html").Links.href` (or `(iwr "http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html").Links.href-match":"` for only absolute URI's)

Comment: That's pretty handy!

Answer (score 23):

## D

```
import std.net.curl, std.stdio;
import std.algorithm, std.regex;

void main() {
foreach(_;byLine("http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html")
    .map!((a)=>a.matchAll(regex(`<a.*?href="(.*)"`)))
    .filter!("a")){ writeln(_.front[1]); }
}
```

Comment: To make the list similar to the original example, you could pipe the program's output through `| sort | uniq` or instead add `import std.array` and change the line `.filter!("a")){ writeln(_.front[1]); }` into this: `.filter!("a").map!(a => a.front[1]).array.sort.uniq){ writeln(_); }`.  Note, however, that I have only tried this code and not proved it to be correct or "idiomatic". :)

Answer (score 21):

## Node.js

```js
var http = require('http');

http.get('http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html', function (res) {
    var data = '';
    res.on('data', function (d) {
        data += d;
    }).on('end', function () {
        console.log(data.match(/"https?:\/\/.*?"/g));
    }).setEncoding('utf8');
});
```

Comment: I wonder if `require('http').get` works. If it does then we can ditch the var statement and shorten another line.

Comment: @Unihedro It does.

Comment: @Unihedro It does, but this isn't a golfing contest.

Comment: You don’t need to use any capturing groups.

Comment: I think it's JavaScript rather than a framework name.

Answer (score 21):

## Haskell

Some troubles with `"\w"` in Text.Regex.Posix

```hs
import Network.HTTP
import Text.Regex.Posix
pattern = "((http://)?www([./#\\+-][a-zA-Z]*)+)"
site = "http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html"

main = do
    file <- getResponseBody =<< simpleHTTP (getRequest site)
    let result = getAllTextMatches $ file =~ pattern
    putStr $ unlines result -- looks nicer
```

Comment: Why is the type of `result` specified explicitly? It should be fully constrained by its use in `unlines`.

Comment: This does stretch the rules a bit, seeing as neither `Network.HTTP` nor `TextRegex.Posix` are in the `base` package. (Though they are in the Haskell Platform, and of course on Hackage, so...)

Comment: @JanDvorak, I start to write in ghci (probably i should post it unchanged). But your note is relevant, thanks.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, did not know. It looks like I could not have done, if had used the base package.

Comment: `network` isn't in `base` either, so save for rolling your own socket bindings there's no practical way to do it with just `base`.

Answer (score 19):

## Ruby

```ruby
require 'net/http'
result = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse('http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html'))
result.scan(/"((http)s?://.*?)"/)
```

Comment: Your regex will fail, you need to use `%r{"(https?://[^"]+)"}`. Also you can use `Net::HTTP.get('www.stroustrup.com', '/C++.html')` to shorten up request (and keep it readable). So whole code can be in one line (keeping it readable): `puts Net::HTTP.get("www.stroustrup.com", "/C++.html").scan(%r{"(https?://[^"]+)"})`. Run it with `ruby -rnet/http` and you don't even need `require 'net/http'` line.

Answer (score 18):

## PHP

As far as I can tell, most modern PHP installations come with DOM processing, so here's one that actually traverses the anchors inside the HTML:

```php
foreach (@DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile('http://stroustrup.com/C++.html')->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a) {
    if (in_array(parse_url($url = $a->getAttribute('href'), PHP_URL_SCHEME), ['http', 'https'], true)) {
        echo $url, PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

The inner loop could be shortened to:

```php
preg_match('~^https?://~', $url = $a->getAttribute('href')) && printf("%s\n", $url);
```

Comment: Actually wanted to come up w this (as my first answer here). You did it first, so here's your +1 (for not using an error prone Regex)! Hint: You could use a lame `1` instead of the `true` for the `in_array` strict search. You can as well omit the brackets. I'm not completely sure, but iirc you could as well drop the `http` and only leave the `://` (go w/o the scheme). .

Comment: And: Another possibility would be to drop the `if ( ) {}` in favor of `in_array() and print $url.PHP_EOL`. But yeah, you would get another +1 (if I could) for **best readability** :)

Comment: Just tried your example and got an error for strict standards (PHP 5.4). Seems like in the source, there's somewhere a corrupted or wrongly formatted link with a missing semicolon. You could turn off error reporting by using `@\DOMDocument`. Just tried that and can confirm it works.

Comment: Nah, it's the documentation that's wrong; technically you're not supposed to call `::loadHTMLFile()` statically, and adding `@` only hides that artefact.

Comment: Yeah, that's the thing I know. I just didn't make myself clear: Both errors (strict and missing semicolon) aren't related. Just do the DOM loop line by line to see for yourself. You can set  `error_reporting( E_ALL ^ E_STRICT );` and the error still is there. **Edit:** Here's [a Gist to play around with](https://gist.github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/b4651103168a56dbd4ed). Just remove the `@`/error suppression from the `loadHTMLFile()` call. :)

Comment: Although they're not strictly related, the silencing operator "fixes" both issues; also, the target HTML document is crap :P

Comment: This is definitely one of the most "correct" solutions, one of the only ones I could see in use in production. nice job

Answer (score 14):

## Unix Shell

```
wget -q -O - http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html | sed -n '/http:/s/.*href="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p' | sort
```

Though i have to admit this doesn't work if there's more than one link on a line.

Comment: `curl http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html` saves a few characters.

Comment: *"but no third-party libraries are allowed"*.  I guess since `wget` is GNU (as is bash), you could argue that it is not third-party.  But `curl` definitely is third-party.

Comment: What about `ftp://ftp.research.att.com/pub/c++std/WP/CD2` and `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jDqQudbtuqo&feature=youtu.be`?

Comment: @TobiasKienzler I guess Stroustrup's original code doesn't find them either

Answer (score 14):

## Java

```java
import java.util.regex.*;
class M{
    public static void main(String[]v)throws Throwable{
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile( "\"((http)s?://.*?)\"" )
            .matcher(
                 new Scanner(
                         new URL( "http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html" )
                             .openStream(),
                         "UTF-8")
                     .useDelimiter("\\A")
                     .next());
        while(m.find())
            System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you properly format code in your answers? It isn't competition for the least readable code. You can format it to avoid horizontal scrollbars at least.

Comment: If you use a `Scanner` you can make it processing the regex pattern for links directly and iterate over the `Scanner`’s results.

Comment: Yep .. that's java for you.  Using it for code golf is a brave undertaking.

Comment: Never thought I'd see a java solution that's actually shorter than C++!

Comment: Good job, but I think it can be made less verbose with some lambdas.

Comment: Correction to my last comment: I must admit this is pretty much the shortest and cleanest code that can be written in Java. I've tried a SAX parser approach, which could be made even shorter with lambdas, but the web page is not XHTML and the parser throws exceptions. Regex is the only way to go.

Comment: If you can use JSoup, you can make it nicer still, but I don't know what the rules are around using external libraries for this.

Comment: @javadba Java is not worse than other languages, it only needs to be used correctly. As hinted in [my old comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44278//44292#comment103549_44285), this answer is abusing the tool which can do the entire job for just getting the entire page as string, followed by unnecessary manual regex matching. With recent Java versions you can do it like: `new Scanner(new URL("http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html").openStream(), "UTF-8") .findAll("\"(https?://.*?)\"").forEach(m -> System.out.println(m.group(1)));` though real code would use `try(…)` for cleanup…

Answer (score 11):

## Groovy

```
"http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html".toURL().text.findAll(/https?:\/\/[^"]+/).each{println it}
```

Comment: Could be improved by using ?. operator to avoid NPEs?

Comment: @ChrisKaminski and be the first (beside Bjarne) around here to check for errors?  never!  beside that: i only see IO related exceptions here.  where do you see a NPE?

Comment: findAll() could return null, no?  Or will it return an empty list?  Still a bit new to Groovy.  EDIT:  nm, looks like findAll() returns an empty list.  Those Groovy guys were so smart.  :-)

Answer (score 11):

## SQL (SQL Anywhere 16)

### Define a stored procedure to fetch the web page

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CPPWebPage()
URL 'http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html'
TYPE 'HTTP';
```

### Produce the result set using a single query

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(Value,'"https?://[^""]+"',1,row_num) AS Link  
FROM (SELECT Value FROM CPPWebPage() WITH (Attribute LONG VARCHAR, Value LONG VARCHAR) 
      WHERE Attribute = 'Body') WebPage, 
      sa_rowgenerator( 1, 256 ) 
WHERE Link IS NOT NULL;
```

Limitations: This produces up to 256 links. If more links exist, then bump up the 256 to an appropriate value.

Comment: I didn't believe there would be golf in SQL... until now.

Comment: I get it ... "links". :-)

Answer (score 10):

## CoffeeScript / NodeJS

```coffeescript
require('http').get 'http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html', (r) ->
    dt = '';
    r.on 'data', (d) -> dt += d
    r.on 'end' , (d) -> console.log dt.match /"((http)s?:\/\/.*?)"/g
```

Comment: I guess this is CoffeeScript/Node? I guess you should specify that...

Comment: Wow. That's very readable.

Comment: @slebetman it definitely is small though

Comment: @slebetman Yeah CoffeeScript is so much more readable than JavaScript :) I was glad to get rid of all the curly braces }:)

Answer (score 9):

### Perl

```perl
use LWP;
use feature 'say';

my $agent = new LWP::UserAgent();
my $response = $agent->get('http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html');

say for $response->content =~ m<"(https?://.+?)">g;
```

Comment: The code would be more clear if you avoided the field-separator and record-separator variables and just did:

  print map { "$_\n" }
    $response->content =~ m<"(https?://.+?)">g;

Comment: @DanielRuoso agreed.

Comment: or even `use v5.10;` and `say for $response->content`...

Comment: To each his own, I suppose.  Some of the backported perl6 features have been problematic (smart matching, I'm looking at you), but `say` is quite useful, and in my mind clearer here.  (Also, there have been rather a lot of completely-unrelated-to-perl6ism improvements to perl5 in the last 13 years; it might be worth checking out.)

Comment: @MarkReed I agree that `say` is probably more readable in this case, particularly for those less familiar with perl.

Answer (score 9):

## R

```r
html<-paste(readLines("http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html"),collapse="\n")
regmatches(html,gregexpr("http[^([:blank:]|\\\"|<|&|#\n\r)]+",html))
```

...although R is written mainly in C... so probably a few lines of C code behind those 2 lines of R code.

Comment: That (or something similar) is true for pretty much all the answers here.

Answer (score 8):

**Objective-C**

```
NSString *s;
for (id m in [[NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\"((http)s?://.*?)\"" options:0 error:nil] matchesInString:(s=[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html"]])]){
    NSLog(@"%@",[s substringWithRange:[m range]]);
}
```

Comment: What? Please write the Swift version. That square bracket nonsense is hurting my eyes :)

Comment: Hurray for []!
Also, we should totally add a Smalltalk version ;)

Comment: @MisterSmith Swift answer now available [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/81079/19617).

Answer (score 7):

## Go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get("http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    results := regexp.MustCompile(`https?://[^""]+`).FindAll(data, -1)
    for _, row := range results {
        fmt.Println(string(row))
    }
}
```

**P.S.** this code reads entire source into memory, so consider using `regexp.FindReaderIndex` to search in stream, that'll make the app bulletproof.

Answer (score 7):

### Tcl

```
package require http
set html [http::data [http::geturl http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html]]
puts [join [regexp -inline -all {(?:http://)?www(?:[./#\+-]\w*)+} $html] \n]
```

Comment: You can get away by doing http::data inside the puts. No need to create a temporary variable. And I'd also format it by putting newlines and indenting at every `[`. But that's a style choice.

Answer (score 6):

## CJam

CJam does not have regex so I had to use a different approach in this one:

```
"http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html"g''/'"*'"/(;2%{_"http://"#!\"https://"#!e|},N*
```

I first convert all `'` to `"`, then I split on all `"`, take every alternative string and then finally filter that list for strings starting with `http://` or `https://`. After that, simply print each filtered string on a new line.

Try it using the [Java interpreter](http://sourceforge.net/p/cjam/wiki/Home/) like

```
java -jar cjam-0.6.2.jar file.cjam
```

where file.cjam has the contents of the code above.

Comment: Don't know about the readable part... didn't know Cjam has web functionality

Comment: If you want to golf it... ``''/'"f/:+`` for ``''/'"*'"/'"f/0f=``.

Comment: ...wait why is ``'"f/0f=`` there? Is that supposed to do something (`2%` for instance)?

Answer (score 6):

## F#

This code could be far shorter but I would write something like this if I ever expected to have to read or use this code again so it has many unnecessary type annotations.  It demonstrates the use of an active pattern *MatchValue* to enable pattern-matching against the standard CLR type *Match*

```ml
open System.Net

let (|MatchValue|) (reMatch: Match) : string = reMatch.Value

let getHtml (uri : string) : string = 
    use webClient = WebClient() in
        let html : string = webClient.DownloadString(uri)
        html

let getLinks (uri : string) : string list =
    let html : string = getHtml uri
    let matches : MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(html, @"https?://[^""]+") 
    let links = [ for MatchValue reMatch in matches do yield reMatch ]
    links

let links = getLinks "http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html" 
for link in links do
    Console.WriteLine(link)
```

**Edit**
I made getLinks its own function

Comment: I really like how you used type annotations. I think naming values to describe what you return is ok, but name of the function is expressive enough: getHTML and html value, getLinks and links value. Last two lines may be links |> Seq.iter (printfn "%s")

Comment: @MichalMa I agree that the name of the function is expressive enough on its own, the html and links variables are there for pragmatic reasons: so there is somewhere to set a breakpoint.  I used the for loop instead of List.iter just because I like the way it reads more, although in a repl I probably would have used List.iter.

Answer (score 6):

## Rebol

```
parse read http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html [
    any [
        thru {<a href="} copy link to {"} (print to-string link)
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 5):

## Delphi

```pascal
program Links;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}
uses
  System.SysUtils, idHTTP, RegularExpressions;
var
  client: TidHTTP;
  match : TMatch;
begin
  client := TidHTTP.Create;
  try
    match := TRegEx.Create('<a(.*)href="(.*)">(.*)<\/a>', [roIgnoreCase, roMultiline])
      .match(client.Get('http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html'));
    with match do
      while Success do
      begin
        if Groups.Count >= 3 then
          if copy(lowercase(Groups[2].Value), 1, 4) = 'http' then
              writeln(Groups[2].Value);
        match := NextMatch;
      end;
  finally
    client.Free;
  end;
end.
```

This would work in (I suppose) Delphi XE and later. It requires no component other than those that are already installed in a default setup (namedly indy and regular expressions). Even tho delphi is quite close to C++ in general structure, I guess this task turned out to be a bit shorter.

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby

Another Ruby solution:

```ruby
require 'open-uri'
open('http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html', 'r:iso-8859-1:utf-8') do |f|
  puts f.read.scan(%r{"(https?://www[^"]*)"}).sort
end
```

Answer (score 4):

## MATLAB

Is quite straightforward with urlread and regexp:

```matlab
url = 'http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html';
links = regexp(urlread(url), '<a href="http://([^"]*\.*)">', 'tokens');
```

Answer (score 4):

## Scala

```scala
object Downloader extends App {
    val s = io.Source.fromURL("http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html", "iso-8859-1").mkString // load URL to String
    val regex = """((http://)?www([./#\+-]\w*)+)""".r                                      // create and compile regexp
    println(regex.findAllIn(s).mkString("\n"))                                             // print matches
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## F#

```fs
open System.Net
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

let html = (new WebClient()).DownloadString("http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html") in
    Regex.Matches(html, @"https?://[^""]+") |> Seq.cast<Match> |> Seq.iter (printfn "%A")
```

Taken from the C# version.

Answer (score 4):

## SmallTalk (Pharo 3)

> Hurray for []! Also, we should totally add a Smalltalk version ;)

@Bersaelor at Objective-C answer.

I know basics of Smalltalk - syntax of language and some tutorials. I decide that it's good place for practice. I have already installed Pharo 3.0.

> but no third-party libraries are allowed

Okay. On downloaded image I found Zinc-HTTP and regex packages.  Probably I should read about "third-party" meaning.

So, code:

```pl
(ZnClient new get: 'http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html')
   regex: '((http\://)?www([./#+-]\w*)+)' matchesDo: [ :x | Transcript show: String cr, x ].
```

Code with exception handlings:

```pl
|response|
[  
response := (ZnClient new url: 'http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html'; get; response).
response isSuccess 
  ifFalse: [ Transcript show: 'Bad status : ', (response status asString) ]
  ifTrue:  [ response contents regex: '((http\://)?www([./#+-]\w*)+)' matchesDo: 
           [ :x | Transcript show: String cr, x ]]
]
    on: NameLookupFailure do: [ Transcript show: 'Connection problem...' ].
```

If you try to check me out you will get an exception. Something like `UTF8EncoderException: errorIllegalLeadingByte`. The first thing I thought that the package pretty outdated. But then realized that it downloads other sites well. Then I thought it is not always well copes with utf8. In debug received byte = 150 (1001 0110) - it's bad if it is the first byte in sequence. I spent a some time on the localization error (moved up in call stack and found parsed line). So:

[image: Ehh]

> Lang.Next'14 Keynote: What � if anything � have we learned from C++? A 68 minute talk incl. Q&A.

You should see here squares or diamonds with question marks, depending on your browser. Trap from Stroustrup. At best, I had to write an exception handler in the package at the point where the line is created. But i just comment exception call and return `?` character.

[image: remove exception call]

Also in code which calc the sequence length I return 1 in place of exception call (seems browsers does same).

P.S. some notes about Pharo (if anyone interested):

- Too much GUI
- Frendly for beginners.
- Nice package searching
- Nice highlighting and code autocompletion (not nice enough for serios IDE like IDEA but better than what I saw a few years ago in the same Pharo). Autocompletion sometimes trying deduce type - very thankless job.
- Very chaotic GUI. At IDE we used to see tiled windows system, but there is only floating litle windows.
- Where is imports, namespaces? There are many entities already. Is never a collision occurs?

Answer (score 4):

## Vimscript

```
function! Cpp()
    " grab the page in a new buffer in a new window in a new tab page
    tabedit http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html

    " delete all lines that don't contain at least one 'http' hyperlink
    v/"http/d

    " only keep the hyperlink on every line
    %s/^.\+="\([^"]\+\)".\+$/\1
endfunction
```

Answer (score 3):

**JS/jQuery**

```
$.get('http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html',{},function(s){
    $(s).find('a').each(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr('href'))
    })
})
```

Comment: jQuery is a third-party library. You should use plain JavaScript.

Comment: @Athari if Mr. Stroustrup allows Boost for C++, jQuery should be fine for JS `:P`

Comment: This will only work if executed from the stroustrup domain since cross domain XHR requests need to be handled specifically by the server.

Comment: This answer has examples of jquey makings both easier and harder.  The XHR is drastically simpler, and getting the href attribute out of the dom object is needlessly more complicated.

Comment: @SethBattin Could you show us a simpler approach to getting the href attributes?

Comment: @JLRishe sure.  `this.href`

Comment: @SethBattin Oh, you just meant that one little bit. Well, I wouldn't call that needlessly more complicated. Sacrificing a few extra characters for consistency isn't the end of the world.

Comment: @JLRishe I'm not bothered by the few characters; it's still perfectly readable and short.  But it's also generating a complex jquery object to wrap around an already complex DOM object, and then accessing a property through a string lookup.  It could get there in one step rather than...lots of steps.  Consistency is great, but that kind of line makes me think it was applied by reflex.  Everything gets wrapped in `$(...)` all the time, whether it needs it or not, i.e.  jQuery because jQuery.  That's the aspect I don't like.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2

I don't like using regex on HTML for [established reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/321973), so here's an ungolfed [HTMLParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) approach:

```python
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
import urllib2 as u

class LinkFinder(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag=='a':
            attrdct = dict(attrs)  # attrs is a list of ('key', 'value') tuples
            if 'href' in attrdct:
                href = attrdct['href']
                print href

url = "http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html"
contents = u.urlopen(url).read()
LinkFinder().feed(contents)
```

Note this also gives local links such as `index.html` and anchors à la `#learning`. If you only want absolute links, prepend `print href` by

```python
                if ':/' in href:  # also handles ftp, https etc.
                    print href
```

while for only omitting the anchors, use

```python
                if !href.startswith('#'):
                    print href
```

Answer (score 3):

## Lua

Here's a lua solution complete with error checking and duplicate URL elimination like Stroustrups's C++ version.

Just made it in under 10 lines

```lua
local http, urlunique = require 'socket.http', {}

local body, resp, _, respmsg = http.request "http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html"
assert(resp == 200, respmsg or resp)
for each in body:gmatch 'https?://[^%s<>"]+' do
  if not urlunique[each] then
    urlunique[each] = true
    print(each)
    end end
```

Here's another version using `string.gsub` fitting in just 6 lines!

```lua
local http, urlunique = require 'socket.http', {}

local body, resp, _, respmsg = http.request "http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html"
assert(resp == 200, respmsg or resp)
body:gsub ('https?://[^%s<>"]+', function(r) urlunique[r] = true end)
for url in pairs(urlunique) do print(url) end
```

Answer (score 3):

## VBScript in Windows Script Host

That is, if this is stored in `links.vbs` file, run it via `cscript /nologo links.vbs`.

```basic
sub writeline( s ): WScript.StdOut.WriteLine s : end sub
function re( s ): set re = new RegExp: re.pattern = s: re.global = true: end function

set http = createobject( "Msxml2.XMLHTTP" )
http.open "GET", "http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html", false: http.send
set links = re( "\w+://[^\""]+" ).execute( http.responseText )
for each link in links: writeline( link ): next
```

---

**Addendum:**

While the above lists all full links, which seems to be the goal, Stroustrup’s code additionally pares it down to ***unique* links**, and here’s a version that does that:

```basic
sub writeline( s ): WScript.StdOut.WriteLine s : end sub
function re( s ): set re = new RegExp: re.pattern = s: re.global = true: end function

set http = createobject( "Msxml2.XMLHTTP" )
http.open "GET", "http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html", false: http.send
set links = re( "\w+://[^\""]+" ).execute( http.responseText )

set unique_links = createobject( "Scripting.Dictionary" )
on error resume next
for each link in links: unique_links.add ucase(link), link & "": next
for each link in unique_links.items(): writeline( link ): next
```

This reduces the number of output lines from 81 to 77.

Answer (score 3):

## **Rust**

Here is Rust solution:

```
extern crate reqwest;
extern crate select;
extern crate regex;

use select::document::Document;
use select::predicate::Name;
use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    scrape_links("http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html");
}

fn scrape_links(url: &str) {
    let resp = reqwest::get(url).unwrap();
    assert!(resp.status().is_success());
    let re = Regex::new(r"((http://)?www([./#\+-]\w*)+)").unwrap();
    Document::from_read(resp)
        .unwrap()
        .find(Name("a"))
        .filter_map(|n| n.attr("href"))
        .filter(|text| re.is_match(text))
        .for_each(|x| println!("{}", x));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## R

I'm super new to regex so I gave this my best shot... any improvements appreciated!

```
grep("(http)s?://.*?", readLines("http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html"), value = T)
```

`readLines()` just dumps the HTML source into a character vector. I then used `grep()` to find the URLs. The problem I ran into was that HTML element tags as well as corresponding link text were included in the output. `substring()` could be used to trim some of them I guess but it wouldn't work in all cases. If anyone knows a better way please let me know - especially if I could use a better regex.

Comment: regex is not only not mandatory, it is actually a rather bad method for parsing HTML. Anyway, your code is obviously much more concise than the C++ one :)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2.7

Some readable Python code.

```python
import urllib2
import re
page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html").read()
for link in re.findall('"(http[s]?://.*?)"', page):
    print link
```

Answer (score 2):

## (C++)--

### *aka C*

I'm suprised no one has done C yet.  The code is nice and clean.

linkfetch.c:

```c
#include "inet_utils.h"
main(){
  char* SITE="www.stroustrup.com";
  char* PAGE="C++.html";
  char* REGX="((http://)?www([./#\\+-]\\w*)+)";
  int s = connect_to(SITE);
  FILE* f = fetch_page(s,SITE,PAGE);
  if (f) list_matches(f,REGX);
  else return printf("Can't fetch page %s/%s\n",SITE,PAGE);
  fclose(f); close(s);
}
```

That is, clean assuming you also write these simple utiliies:

inet_utils.h

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <regex.h>

#define SZ 1024 //good default buffer size
#define ERROR(s) (puts(s)&&0)
#define VP(e) ((void*)(long)(e))

inline int connect_to(char* w){
  //:returns socket connected to website w.
  struct sockaddr_in a;
  int s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);                       // make socket
  struct hostent* h = gethostbyname(w);                        // lookup host
  if (!h) return ERROR("No Such Host");                        // check err
  a.sin_family=AF_INET;                                        // set ip address
  a.sin_port=htons(80);                                        // port 80
  memcpy(&a.sin_addr.s_addr, h->h_addr, h->h_length);          // of host
  if (connect(s,(struct sockaddr*)&a,sizeof(a))<0)             // connect
    return ERROR("can't connect");                             // handle error
  return s;                                                    // return socket
}

inline FILE* fetch_page(int s, char*w, char* p){
  //:returns open file handle for page p from site w connected to socket s

  FILE*f=fopen("/tmp/wcache","w+");                   // create cache file
  size_t n; char*b=malloc(SZ);                        // allocate temp buffer
  if (!s||!f||!b) return VP(ERROR("Resource Error")); // check for errors
  sprintf(b,                                          // compose request
          "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost:%s\r\nAccept:*/*\r\nConnection:close\r\n\r\n",
          w);
  send(s,b,strlen(b),0);                         // send request
  while ((n=recv(s,b,SZ,0))>0)                   // receive response
    fwrite(b,1,n,f);                             // write it to cache file
  fseek(f,n=0,SEEK_SET);                         // read from beginnng
  fgets(b,SZ,f);                                 // look at first line
  if (!f||strncmp(strtok(b," "),"HTTP/",5))      // is it http?
    return VP(ERROR("Invalid Response"));        // error if not
  if (atoi(strtok(0," "))!=200)                  // check good status code
    return VP(ERROR("Bad Status Code"));         // error if not
  while (getline(&b,&n,f)>=0 && *b!='\r');       // skip headers upto blank line
  free(b);                                       // cleanup
  return f;                                      // return open handle
}

inline void list_matches(FILE* f, char* regx){
  //prints all strings from f which match regx
  regex_t r;
  size_t n = SZ; char*b=malloc(n);               // temp buffer
  if (regcomp(&r,regx,REG_NOSUB|REG_EXTENDED))   // compile regex
    puts("invalid regex");                       // handle error
  else while (getline(&b,&n,f)>0)                // fetch line
         if (!regexec(&r,b,0,0,0))               // check match
           puts(b);                              // show match
  regfree(&r); free(b);                          // cleanup
}
```

It compiles without warnings on out-of-the-box gcc (version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) )

Comment: Whether the code readable is highly questionble, considering weird formatting. Comments are nice, but how about properly formatting the code? You don't normally put multiple declarations with assignments, if and return on a single line, do you?

Comment: Clean and readable special purpose C usually comes by hiding ugly general purpose APIs and memory management details in "here be dragons"  wrapper functions.  I  could have prettified the 2nd part,  but it still wouldn't be nice. So I went for condensed instead.

Comment: This is ridiculous. Tell Linus about C code being unreadable by design. Properly formatted code is much easier to understand, there's nothing "magic" in your mess besides crazy formatting. http://pastebin.com/WHrqJzXb

Comment: Fine, here's some formatting. I didn't say C is unreadable by design, I said general purpose APIs are _usually_ less readable than special purpose ones.  And I point to the gymnastics needed to populate the address for connecting to a web host as an example.

Answer (score 2):

## Swift (2.2)

> What? Please write the Swift version. That square bracket nonsense is hurting my eyes :)

[Mister Smith](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/2793/mister-smith) on the [Objective-C answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44289/19617).

```
let x = try!NSString(contentsOfURL:NSURL(string:"http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html")!,encoding:4)
for y in try!NSRegularExpression(pattern:"\"((http)s?://.*?)\"",options:[]).matchesInString(x as String,options:[],range:NSMakeRange(0,x.length)){print(x.substringWithRange(y.range))}
```

Ungolfed:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html")!
let html = try! NSString(contentsOfURL: url, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\"((http)s?://.*?)\"", options: [])
let results = regex.matchesInString(html as String, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, html.length))
for result in results {
    print(html.substringWithRange(result.range))
}
```

Assumes Foundation has been implicitly imported.

I can't access the original page for some reason, so this was tested with the Google Cached version: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:USk4BseSofcJ:www.stroustrup.com/C%2B%2B.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

282 bytes.  Slightly shorter than the 292 byte Objective-C answer.  I'm falling back onto Foundation APIs, so there may be room for improvement by using pure Swift types.  The Cocoa APIs have also changed since the Objective-C answer was posted.

`stringWithContentsOfURL:` has been deprecated on `NSString` in favor of `stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:`.  We lose some bytes on the `encoding` parameter, but gain some back because the `ErrorPointer` is no longer passed in with Swift.  The function now `throws` its `NSError` so instead, I'm using `try!` to force the execution of the `NSString` and `NSRegularExpression` initializers.  I also save some bytes by passing the raw value `4` as the value of the `encoding` parameter instead of the constant `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.  19 bytes saved.  But I lose some bytes by having to pass in an empty array (`[]`) instead of `0` to represent no options.  2 bytes lost there.  I also lose two bytes for every variable declaration since Swift requires whitespace characters on either side of the `=` character.

I lose 10 bytes by having to cast the `NSString` as a Swift `String` when calling `matchesInString`.  This is required because I'm using the `NSString` method `contentsOfURL` to get the web page HTML, but the `NSRegularExpression` method `matchesInString` takes in a Swift `String` as a parameter.  The implicit conversion between `NSString` and `String` isn't available here, so I am forced to use `as` to explicitly convert the types.

Interestingly enough `matchesInString` has not been completely converted to use Swift types.  It still requires its `range` parameter to be an `NSRange` struct instead of a Swift `Range<String>`.  I have to fall back and use `NSMakeRange` to create the range of the string.  I could save 4 bytes by using `x.characters.indices` of type `Range<String.CharacterView.Index>` instead, but Swift `Range` structs are not compatible with Foundation `NSRange` structs.  Additionally, if `x` were a Swift `String`, I might be able to save a few bytes by replacing `substringWithRange` with a subscript on `String`.  I haven't found a great way to do that yet, as creating two `Index` structs is currently longer than using `substringWithRange`.

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf. Great answer, well explained, I'm not sure you need any help at all. Quick tip though: the convention on this site is to put your byte count in the title, just after the language name.

Comment: Oh, I've just noticed: This isn't a [tag:code-golf]: its objective is to "show Stroustrup what small and **readable** code is". If you could provide an ungolfed (readable) version, that would be very helpful.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Thank you for your comments.  I didn't see the byte count next to the language name in the other answers, so I just added mine below.  I've also added an ungolfed version to my answer.

Comment: The reason you didn't see a byte count is because this is not a [tag:code-golf] challenge.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Ah, got it.  Still learning.  Thank you!

Comment: Everybody is, even me. Even Dennis!

Comment: @wizzwizz4 also good to see that you're active on retrocomputing!  See you around.

Answer (score 1):

## ColdFusion

(using the same regex that Stroustrup uses)

```
<cfhttp url="http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html" result="response" />
<cfif response.statusCode does not contain "200">
    <cfset writeOutput("Error getting the page: #response.statusCode#") />
<cfelse>
    <cftry>
        <cfset htmlLinks = REMatchNoCase("((http://)?www([./#\+-]w*)+)",response.fileContent) />
        <cfdump var="#htmlLinks#" />
    <cfcatch>
        <cfset writeOutput("There was a problem: #cfcatch.message# #cfcatch.detail#") />
    </cfcatch>
    </cftry>
</cfelse>
```

Comment: @Athari how do you do the code highlighting?

Comment: See [Markdown help - Syntax highlighting for code](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting). The syntax is usually `<!-- language: lang-$LANGUAGE_NAME$ -->` before the code block. If it doesn't work (support for many languages is missing), I look what CSS class is applied on StackOverflow to code blocks in questions for that language.

Answer (score 1):

## XQuery

HTML should be something similar to XML, so why not use langauges designed for this job?

If the page would've been "real" XHTML, we could run a query as beautiful as

```sh
doc("http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html")//a/@href/data()
```

As this is crappy, broken HTML, let's use the [BaseX](http://www.basex.org)-specific HTML parser (BaseX is an XQuery implementation):

```sh
html:parse(fetch:binary("http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html"))//a/@href/data()
```

If limiting to URLs starting with `http:` is a must, lets do it:

```sh
html:parse(fetch:binary("http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html"))//a/@href[starts-with(., 'http:')]/data()
```

*Disclaimer: I am somewhat affiliated with the BaseX team as I wrote some code during my thesis. This would've been the tool of my choice for that kind of task, anyway. Other XQuery implementations provide similar HTML parsing capabilities, but I don't know their XQuery extensions by heart.*

Answer (score 1):

### Bash + AWK

```
wget -q -O http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html \
|awk '/((http:\/\/)?www([./#\+-]\w*)+)/ {print gensub(/.*((http:\/\/)?www([./#\+-]\w*)+).*/,"\\1","g")}'
```

I know it probably misses a few URLs, but I chosen to use the same regex than the original Stroustrup's code, so this should returns the same output than the original piece of code.

It may be possible to add some CR to make it more visible but I don't have a Linux available ATM for testing it works... (tested on Windows)

Here is a "clean" version of the AWK part:

```
/((http:\/\/)?www([./#\+-]\w*)+)/ {
    print gensub(/.*((http:\/\/)?www([./#\+-]\w*)+).*/,"\\1","g")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP 4.3+ / 5.0+

I know there are 2 different answers regarding PHP, but I'm going to show here a similar aproach, using nothing but standard functions.

For this, you will need to have the following on a file named `php.ini` ON THE SAME DIRECTORY:

```
allow_url_fopen= On
allow_url_include= On
```

THAT PART IS IMPORTANT!
In case you can't change (didn't worked with XAMPP), you have a default `php.ini` file on the PHP installation folder.
Changing the values will solve it.
Remember to restart apache after.

Since this isn't [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), I made my code somewhat readable.

Here it is:

```php
ob_start(); //creates an output buffer

//now we 'include' the file, which will output the source code.
include 'http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html';

$html = ob_get_clean(); //stores the output buffer and closes it

$offset = 0; //initial offset to search
$links = array(); //will contain all links

//while a link is found
while($pos = strpos($html, 'href="http', $offset))
{
    //look for the closing "
    $end = strpos($html, '"', $pos + 7);
    //take it from the string, store it into the array
    $links[] = substr($html, $pos + 6, ($end - $pos) - 6);
    //increase the offset, so it doesn't find the same link again
    $offset = $end + 1;
}

print_r($links); //spits it out, with the output buffer closed
```

I've added some comments to try to explain the code.

No regex used or DOM parsers: only pure hard-cold string manipulation.

For this to work in other pages, you must be sure that the values of the property `href` are between `""`, or it will fail.

Answer (score 1):

## F#

```fs
do
  use client = new System.Net.WebClient()
  let html = client.DownloadString "http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html"
  System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(html, @"https?://[^""]+")
  |> Seq.cast<System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match>
  |> Seq.iter (printfn "%O")
```

Answer (score 0):

## CSS - idea

In Firefox, for example, for any page you are on, you can go to Tools | Web Developer | Style Editor, and use CSS to display anchors only:

```
* {display:none;}
a {display:block;}
```

However, the above *will not* work because `display` of parent elements overrides children.

Still working on a CSS solution, but suggestions welcome!

Comment: Maybe using positioning?  Push everything off the page to the left, then push links back on to the right?

Comment: @Izkata - looks like I've been scooped by Athari who provided a CSS solution!

Comment: You could use "* {font-size:0pt} a {font-size:8pt}" to display only the links, but you won't see the URLs

Comment: It seems Athari nailed it :)

Answer (score 0):

### C++/U++

Here is the U++ (which is 'another' C++ library, slightly different approach from boost) version:

```
#include <Core/Core.h>
#include <plugin/pcre/Pcre.h>

using namespace Upp;

CONSOLE_APP_MAIN
{
    String s = ToCharset(CHARSET_UTF8, HttpRequest("http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html").Execute(),
                         CHARSET_ISO8859_1);
    RegExp x("href *= *\"(.*?)\"");
    while(x.GlobalMatch(s))
        Cout() << x.GetStrings()[0] << "\n";
}
```

(BTW, funny how most versions here are IMO not implementing the original specification: extract all links. There are many links on that page that do not start with http...)

Comment: Kudos, I just posted the same below (deleted now), and equally tried to reply to the original post ( BTW: http://www.ultimatepp.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=9167&start=0& ) but it won't let me to post links as a first message.

Answer (score 0):

## Lua

More concise, without checking for errors or unique URLs:
In readable...

```
http = require 'socket.http'
page = http.request 'http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html'
page:gsub('http://www[%w./#\\+-]+', print)
```

...and less-readable...

```
require'socket.http'.request'http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html':gsub('http://www[%w./#\\+-]+',print)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript / DOM

```javascript
var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
r.open('GET', 'http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html', false);
r.send(null);
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = r.response;
[].slice.call(div.getElementsByTagName('a')).forEach( function(a) {
  if (a.href && a.getAttribute('href').charAt(0) != '#') console.log(a.href);
} );
```

(Tested in the Google Chrome javascript console.)

Of course, CORS blocks this by default - but its easy [to disable CORS in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome) for development purposes.

Comment: `r.response` is a string.  You have to set `r.responseType = "document"` first.  But then, you get an error because the request is synchronous.

Comment: Thanks @gilly3.  I've modified it to take the text response and put it in a div's innerHTML instead.  When running the browser with CORS disabled, this definitely now works.

Answer (score -1):

## Bash

```
 GET http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html | grep -o "https\?://[^ \"]\+
```

needs libwww-perl and grep packages :)